# How can I reset a Windows process to a previous state?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, process

I have a large application with a lot of threads and a lot of complex static objects. Currently, when a user logs out, the application is restarted to forcefully reset the application to it's initial state.

This process is being changed to a Windows service, so this approach is no longer possible. Likewise, the code is too much of a mess to properly implement a way to reset state when a user logs out.

I was thinking there might be an approach with writing the entire process's initial memory to disk, then loading it when a reset is requested, but this has many problems, such as not being able to save the kernel-mode state.

I need a way (however dirty) to reset this process to it's initial state, without actually restarting the process. Does winapi provide anything that can accomplish this for me?

Comment: How about create a new application pool on reset and all of the objects in there?

Comment: If I understand what you're suggesting, the application news __a lot__ of objects without storing the pointers to them anywhere. They're intended to just float around in memory and do their thing until the application closes. I'm not sure if this is very possible.

Comment: EDIT: Oops, I meant Application Domain not pool... Killing an application domain is a lot like the application exiting. Not sure if that helps you though. It has it's own memory 'protected' memory, almost a full process, but not. ;)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx

Comment: Ah. Application domains are actually CLR black magic, it's not operating system-level, so native code can't use them. :(

Comment: Oh god... @dauphic how'd I miss that you were looking at C/C++. Funny.

Comment: If it is user specific (the fact you reset it on logout confirms this) why is it being made system global (a service)? Remember that services can't (directly) interact with a user session.

Comment: In the future, it will support multiple sessions, but right now this is beyond the scope of what we have time for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing preventing a Windows service from doing it's real work in a separate process, although admittedly it's a little messy.  So I would suggest that you have two exectuables: a parent process, implemented as a service, and a child process, which can exit (and be restarted by the parent) whenever you need to reset the application's state.

Answer (score 2):

Windows won't help you here. You will have to solve the problem in your own code rather than looking for a silver bullet. You say

> The code is too
>   much of a mess to properly implement a way to reset state
>   when a user logs out.

You will have to re-consider that since it's your only option.

Answer (score 0):

Without re-writing everthing (which you should do), you could just move all of your current logic into a worker thread, then the service can spawn, terminate, and re-spawn that thread whenever needed.  The service process itself would stay running.

Comment: Forcefully terminating a thread should be considered a weapon of absolute last resort.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't believe Windows can spawn a thread that acts as a process, can it? It would need to have it's own memory and system resources.

Comment: I think you both missed the point I was trying to make. Move the current logic into the new service projct, but whatever was in the *current* application's main thread would now be its own worker thread in the service. When the thread starts, it allocates/initializes what it needs. When it stops, it frees/releases everything it needs. The service can then start a new instance of that thread when it detects a login, and **gracefully** stop that thread when it detects a logout.  No brute-force termination, no separate process.

Comment: Another option would be to change the current application into a UI-less console application, then the new service can spawn a new process for that app upon login, and kill the spawned process upon logout.